# Custom Chart with Highcharts / Highstock

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I'm trying to create a custom chart based on the Highstock Basic Line Chart.

To be more exact I'd like to create a drawdown-chart (see [drawdown chart on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drawdown_%28economics%29)). I don't want to discuss the formula :), but the way to change the data display in Highstock/Highcharts following a certain rule. It could be a more simple one: imagine you want to display f(x) = 100 for every data point although your data is completely different.

The following requirements shall be fulfilled:

1. I want to use as much functionality as possible from Highstock like scaling the chart axes, call redraw on "dragging" the time line, etc.
2. I want to use the Highstock patterns to extend its charts: wrapping or pushing event listeners and in doing so, ensuring my code stays readable and maintainable.

The best try was to wrap the `processData` function. In its body I manipulated `xData` and `yData` and called the super method as explained here: [Extending Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts)

The chart broke displaying certain time ranges. The original data seemed to be displayed there.

I can't get any further unaided. I would be really happy if someone could help me with that.

Thanks in advance!

Niels

Comment: 2) What kind of listeners you need, additional events or somehting different?

Answer (score 0):

1) You can catch [redraw](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.redraw) event and then call your actions.

Scalling axis by parameters:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.height
- http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.top

Dynamically

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.update